# OAuth1 reject_token 401 unauthorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, magento-1.9, oauth-1.0a, oauth-ruby

Get Access Token request of OAuth1.0 only work once for Magento1.9 after being redirected back from Authorization URL. Next time when requesting for Access Token I get reject_token.
What I noticed there is difference in signature of both objects' signature.

Request 1(successful):

```
OAuth::Consumer.new(consumer_data)
OAuth::RequestToken.from_hash(some_hash)
request_token.get_access_token(oauth_verifier: 'asdfasdagbadbv')
```

with signature having

```
oauth_nonce=\"iIHmN7obLeONSitOxFFZQI71v0k4mAsEFLFen0Lw\", 
oauth_signature=\"lwj0n1AK3VJLdaXHIWEOFlYp5qc%3D\"
```

Request 2(unsuccessful):

```
OAuth::Consumer.new(consumer_data)
OAuth::RequestToken.from_hash(some_hash)
request_token.get_access_token(oauth_verifier: 'asdfasdagbadbv')
```

with signature having

```
oauth_nonce=\"KciY4tiiPDu1u029Nbdu1C325svchfESTYV1l8mvw\", 
oauth_signature=\"KciY4tiiPt5Du1u029Nbdu1CzCHzvc%3D\"
```

This may be or may not be the issue but this is the only difference I found so far in both requests.
Please someone help me in updating `oauth_nonce` and `signature` or devise some other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem** is in the second line.

```
 request_token.get_access_token(oauth_verifier: 'asdfasdfa')
```

According to [Auth](https://oauth.net/core/1.0/#anchor9) documentation request token should be used one time. Request token expires once we use them. You are using expired request token in the second call **which causes reject_token 401 unauthorized.**

**Solution**

Actually, request tokens are used to generate Access Token. Access Tokens can be used multiple times. So what you need is to store Access Token somewhere, generated in first `request_token.get_access_token(oauth_verifier: 'asdfasdfa')` line. Then you can use saved access token in the reset of your API calls. The syntax of using access token is the following:

```
@consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(...)
@token = OAuth::Token.new('ACCESS_TOKEN', 'ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET') // saved access token and secret here
@consumer.request(:post, '/people', @token, {}, @person.to_xml, { 'Content-Type' => 'application/xml' })
```